# Dynamic Display doesn't respect my annotations when my layers are in a BasemapLayer

Tags: arcgis-engine

I have 2 annotated layers which I load in a BaseMapLayerClass.  When the map is static the annotations are visible.  When I enable DynamicMap I lose all annotations.  I would like a way to annotate layers in a BaseMapLayerClass while dynamic is enabled.

An interesting note about the problem.  If I don't have my layers in a BaseMapLayerClass, dynamic display does not affect my annotations.

However I would like them to be in a BaseMapLayerClass because would make it much easier for me to save layers and restore them across sessions.

I'm using ArcEngine C# VS2010

---

I think the problem is somehow related to extents.

This post: http://briannoyle.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/esri-dynamic-displaysome-limitations/

Led me to the limitations page
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/0b062497-a3fc-4c56-a688-0fb9b2fcb4ea.htm

which states :

*Labels will be cut off on custom layers that don't return the correct extent*

And actually it's weird.  Sometimes the annotations will draw and then I'll move the map up a few pixels with the hand tool, and then they will no longer draw.  Then move it back a few pixels and it will draw again.

It's helpful there is a consistency there, but I haven't a clue how to implement a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a sublayer from BaseMap and casting it into a IGeoFeatureLayer gives null.  So I guess the solution is *do not attempt.*